# Mac Address Flapping and switches

Tags: switching, mac-address, networking

Is mac address flapping the reason why switches don't exchange switching information just like routers exchange routing information?

Comment: You have asked the same question with various accounts four times now. You have received the same answer every time. Please stop posting this question, the answer won’t change. I will delete every next identical question from now on.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Switches don't exchange MAC tables because they don't need to. Each switch is fine with discovering MAC-port associations by itself (self-learning MAC bridge).

MAC address flapping happens when a source MAC continually changes ports from the switch's perspective. This is usually due to misconfiguration or unconfigured redundant links in the network.